# Is there a simple way to make a HTML relational selection?

Tags: javascript, html

There is 4 select tags, each select has 4 options which are 1, 2, 3, 4.
Now, if I randomly select one tag, the other tags options should be reduced.

e.g:

- tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4 are all empty at beginning;

  tag1 is selected with option 2;

  tag2, 3, 4: option: 1, 3, 4 (option 2 is removed);

  tag2 is selected with option 1;

  tag3, 4: option: 3, 4 (option 1 is removed);

  tag3 is selected with option 3;

  tag4: option 4 (option 3 is removed);

  tag4 is selected.

I made it with javascript like that,
but problem is...

After all tags were selected, I want to change one of the tag (and again other tags should automatically changed accordingly)..

Is there any better way to do that?

My code:

```js
           function removeOption()
           {
            var p1 = document.getElementById("player1");
            var p2 = document.getElementById("player2");
            var p3 = document.getElementById("player3");
            var p4 = document.getElementById("player4");
            var selections = [];
            selections.push(p1, p2, p3, p4);
    
            //traversal all the selections, if any not empty, remove its values under all other selections
            var selected = [];
            var unselected = [];
            
            for(var i=0;i<selections.length;i++)
            {
                if(selections[i].value!="empty")
                {
                    var x = selections[i].selectedIndex;
                    selected.push(x);
                }
                else
                {
                    unselected.push(selections[i]);
                }
            }//end of for loop
           
            for(var i=0;i<unselected.length;i++)
            {
                unselected[i].remove(selected[selected.length-1]);
            }
           }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
        <script>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
             <h1>New Players</h1>
        </header>
        <div>
            <form action="./players.php" method="POST">
            Player1: <input type="text" value="Player1">
                <select id="player1" name="player1" onchange="removeOption()">
                    <option value="empty" disabled selected>--Please select--</option>
                    <option value="east">east</option>
                    <option value="south">south</option>
                    <option value="west">west</option>
                    <option value="north">north</option>
                </select>
            <br>
            Player2: <input type="text" value="Player2">
             <select id="player2" name="player2"  onchange="removeOption()">
                    <option value="empty" disabled selected>--Please select--</option>
                    <option value="east">east</option>
                    <option value="south">south</option>
                    <option value="west">west</option>
                    <option value="north">north</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            Player3: <input type="text" value="Player3">
                <select id="player3" name="player3"  onchange="removeOption()">
                    <option value="empty" disabled selected>--Please select--</option>
                    <option value="east">east</option>
                    <option value="south">south</option>
                    <option value="west">west</option>
                    <option value="north">north</option>
                </select>
            <br>
            Player4: <input type="text" value="Player4">
                <select id="player4" name="player4"  onchange="removeOption()">
                    <option value="empty" disabled selected>--Please select--</option>
                    <option value="east">east</option>
                    <option value="south">south</option>
                    <option value="west">west</option>
                    <option value="north">north</option>
                </select>
            <br>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may want to look at using a `change` event listener on each of your `select` fields to trigger the options update.

Comment: I already have onchange event of every select, and I can update the 4 tags correctly. But the problem is the code works only once..I want to change the tags whenever I want...

Comment: Maybe use php+database works...I'll try..

Comment: Post your full code as a snippet so that we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Snippet posted.

Comment: If you select, e.g., *east* in the first element and then *south* in the second one, you are able to come back to the first one and select also *south*. Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: yes. If I come back to the first select also south, then the remain 3 tags should change as well(change to east, west, north...)

Comment: Okay, your code only works once because you're hard coding the initial options, and then removing them after each selection. You actually need to recalculate, and update the available options on every change. I don't have time to write an answer now, but will check back later to see if you're still stuck.

Comment: So you can't rely on the index if you want to do it in that way. Following my example above, after selecting *south* the second time, the unrelated option *west* disappears. Also, the first `select` keep the four options but the last one have just one, which is not intuitive. I don't think is user friendly and the code necessary to achieve it is messy.  Wouldn't be better to keep always the four options? If the user select an option in `player3` that is already in use in `player1`, you just reset `player1`.

Comment: Thanks, fubar, I get it. Thanks you David as well, I think you give me a better idea, I'll make it simple temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more user friendly to keep always the four options.

If the user select an option (*e.g.*) in `player3` that is already in use in `player1`, just reset `player1`.

That also simplifies greatly your code.

Replace `removeOption` with `updateOptions(this)`.

```js
function updateOptions(element) {
  // select all the players but the current one
  var players = document.querySelectorAll("select:not(#" + element.id + ")");
  // iterate just that players
  for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    // if the option was already selected
    if (players[i].value == element.value) {
      // just remove it
      players[i].options[0].selected = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>New Players</h1>
  </header>
  <div>
    <form action="./players.php" method="POST">
      Player1: <input type="text" value="Player1">
      <select id="player1" name="player1" onchange="updateOptions(this)">
        <option value="empty" disabled selected>--Please select--</option>
        <option value="east">east</option>
        <option value="south">south</option>
        <option value="west">west</option>
        <option value="north">north</option>
      </select>
      <br> Player2: <input type="text" value="Player2">
      <select id="player2" name="player2" onchange="updateOptions(this)">
        <option value="empty" disabled selected>--Please select--</option>
        <option value="east">east</option>
        <option value="south">south</option>
        <option value="west">west</option>
        <option value="north">north</option>
      </select>
      <br> Player3: <input type="text" value="Player3">
      <select id="player3" name="player3" onchange="updateOptions(this)">
        <option value="empty" disabled selected>--Please select--</option>
        <option value="east">east</option>
        <option value="south">south</option>
        <option value="west">west</option>
        <option value="north">north</option>
      </select>
      <br> Player4: <input type="text" value="Player4">
      <select id="player4" name="player4" onchange="updateOptions(this)">
        <option value="empty" disabled selected>--Please select--</option>
        <option value="east">east</option>
        <option value="south">south</option>
        <option value="west">west</option>
        <option value="north">north</option>
      </select>
      <br>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```